# Need to match pattern in KSH while parsing lines from file

Tags: sed, grep, ksh

```
FILE_CENT="/etc/nsswitch.conf"

if [[ $OS = 'Linux' ]]; then
 if [[ -e $FILE_CENT ]]; then
  logInfo "nsswitch.conf found in $OS, Proceeding further..."
   while read -r LINE
   do
    if [[ `echo $LINE | sed '/^passwd/'` ]]; then
     myarrlin=($LINE)
     logInfo "ARRAY VALUES : ${myarrlin[0]},${myarrlin[1]},${myarrlin[2]}"
      if [[ `echo ${myarrlin[1]} | egrep -s "centrify$|^centrifydc$"` || `echo ${myarrlin[2]} | egrep -s "centrify$|^centrifydc$"` ]]; then
       IS_ADMIN_ENT_ACC=3
       CENT=1
       logInfo "Centrify is enabled with $OS"
      else
       CENT=0
       logInfo "Centrify is disabled with $OS"
      fi
     fi
   done < $FILE_CENT
  else
  logInfo "nsswitch.conf does not exist in $OS, cannot fetch CENTRIFY information!"
 fi
fi
```

Here, I am using sed and also egrep for pattern matching, but neither of them is giving me correct results.

Also, I am not sure if I can use regex with egrep? Struggling with pattern matching in KSH.

Input :
 [image]

Comment: Pls show input sample data, incorrect, and correct results.

Comment: @RudiC Added the snapshot.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider simplifying your logic to simply asking if the string "centrify" is in the "passwd:" line of /etc/nsswitch.conf. Replace the entire `while` loop with:

```
if grep -q '^passwd:.*centrify' /etc/nsswitch.conf
then
  IS_ADMIN_ENT_ACC=3
  CENT=1
  logInfo "Centrify is enabled with $OS"
else
  CENT=0
  logInfo "Centrify is disabled with $OS"
fi
```